# Exclude of bands lead to excess whitespace

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

## Context

Setup: JasperReports server Product Version: 6.0.1 Build: 20141218_0238, CentOS server. I am using their bundled PostgreSQL + tomcat server setup.

In my report i have a table with text field and static field & and a chart in the summary band.

the static fields are in columnHeader band, and text fields are in the detail band.

I require the table because i want the users to be able to export CSV data.
However when the report is viewed as HTML, i want to exclude the two bands mentioned above (detail/columnHeader).

## Problem

I am able to exclude the table so that it's not showed using the following:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.exclude.origin.band.1=detail
net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.exclude.origin.band.2=columnHeader
```

This does hide the two bands mentioned above, however now instead of the data - whitespace is shown, i would to know how i can remove it

[image: Snippet of issue]

The red text above was added by me, as you can see there are unwanted white-space between the title and the chart, that was where the columnHeader and detail band were at.

See the [JRXML](http://pastebin.com/cP6wETu7) content.

## Question

How can I remove the space?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? If not, please post the JRXML source.

Comment: no i didn't, there is a source from pastebin link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following property to `true`:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.empty.space.between.rows
```

Earlier versions of JasperReports had a typo, for the property (**emtpy** instead of **empty**):

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows
```

For example:

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.emtpy.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
```

Comment: updated question with version info. as for your solution, i did do that, with both (emtpy and empty), but that didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your styles or theme. I run the report in Jasper studio and there was no white space, but I created dummy styles (table_heading, table_data) and set the default theme for bar chart.
Here is my report
http://pastebin.com/fnAnvBR1

I'm using JasperStudio 5.6.2

Comment: i have updated my production version information (new environment setup). anyways, your suggested solution didn't work for me, by themes i assume you mean compiled jrctx (jar files), and by style you mean jrtx . i dont use jrtx for this report, and i have removed the jar theme used for the chart - but the problem has still persisted. any other debugging info that might be useful?

Comment: Did you try with report definition I posted on pastebin? Just copy it in source tab in JasperStudio. Query is for oracle DB so you'll probably have to change that. And by styles, I meant the styles used by report elements, table_heading, table_data. I've defined this two styles in the report, but they have no formatting, the report would not compile without them.

Comment: yeap, just tested it... changed the query/lowercase field names, and tested on updated version of jasper server .. same issue